# Socket.io cdn won't connect and returns a socket.io folder with socket.io.js script that returns an html file in console?

Tags: php, node.js, heroku, socket.io

I deployed my fully functional local php/nodejs app to heroku which is now broken.  The `echo '<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>';` in a php document for heroku returns `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`.  Come to find out, the cdn is not being linked. The heroku server is actually trying to return a script with the path /socket.io/socket.io.js in the console.  Of course that file does not exist, so it is returning a php file (not the file it's included in), hence the `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` because of the html in the random file it's returning.  I have both php and nodejs heroku buildpacks added to my app.  I understand what's happening, just not why nor how to fix it.

Comment: FYI, the link `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` is for use when you the server that your page came from is an Express server with server-side socket.io hooked into it.  If you have that configuation, then the server-side socket.io  will provide the client-side version of socket.io at the link `/socket.io/socket.io.js` and that link will work.  I have no idea how your PHP configuration is affecting this as the server that this link goes to needs to be one or the other, not both.  If you have socket.io server-side code properly installed, you don't need the CDN for client code.

Comment: And, letting the socket.io server provide the socket.io client in this way, automatically keeps the two versions matching.  If you use a  CDN for the client, you HAVE to modify the CDN link every time you upgrade the server-side socket.io code to keep the two version in sync (which is an easy way to break your site if you forget).

Comment: Then the issue was I'm not using express to return my page so src path did not work.  I totally understand, now. I have two backends and got my wires crossed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your analysis is correct. The link to script is wrong.

Here's Socket.io's link: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js

All the CDN links are listed [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/socket.io). Hope this helps!

Comment: Neither heroku nor socket.io say to add the cdn so explicitly (nor does the dozens of so questions I've read about it).  Can't believe this actually worked, thanks a ton!

Comment: Socket.io has this on the website. If this helps, please mark this question as resolved.

Comment: Well, to be more thorough, I started off with a php app and decided to get fancy and add socket.io on the backend of a chat app.  Everything worked fine while I could set the host and port on the client side, but I can't do that in production as the port is an environment variable and it changes.  I think I may just have express serve that particular webpage only.  It's going to suck writing all new code over a port number.  I will mark as resolved.  Thanks!